# Does sudo only apply to a simple command?

Tags: bash, sudo

Does`sudo`  only apply to a simple command? I guess so from the following example. Am I correct or not?

```
$  if true; then echo hello; fi
hello

$ sudo if true; then echo hello; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

$ sudo ( if true; then echo hello; fi )
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `if'

$ sudo "if true; then echo hello; fi"
[sudo] password for t: 
sudo: if true; then echo hello; fi: command not found

$ sudo " ( if true; then echo hello; fi ) "
sudo:  ( if true; then echo hello; fi ) : command not found
```

But I am  not sure when I see this example:

```
$ sudo time echo hello
hello
0.00user 0.00system 0:00.00elapsed 100%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1924maxresident)k
0inputs+0outputs (0major+71minor)pagefaults 0swaps
```

Is `time echo hello`  a simple command? I don't think so, since `time` is a keyword, not a command name.

Thanks.

Comment: `Sudo` is a regular program which is invoked by the shell as any other program, so your attempt at `sudo (...)` is just a syntax mistake. You could try `sudo "(...)"` then the command enclosed in double quotes would be passed to the shell in the context of the `sudo`'ed user

Comment: In `sudo time echo hello` you are executing the external `time` command (e.g. `/usr/bin/time`) rather than your shell's `time`

Comment: @steeldriver  thanks. In `time time`, are both `time` keyword? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444071/is-each-time-in-these-examples-a-keyword-or-usr-bin-time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sudo` doesn't even support the full "simple command" syntax. According to the bash man page, in the Shell Grammar section:

> A *simple command* is a sequence of optional variable assignments
>   followed by **blank**-separated words and redirections, and terminated by
>   a *control operator*.

That is, a simple command might be something like this:

```
LC_ALL=C grep -i "keyword" <infile >outfile &
```

`sudo` supports variable assignments (like `LC_ALL=C`) and a command name and its arguments (like `grep -i "keyword"`), but *does not* support redirections (like `<infile >outfile`) or control operators (`&`). In fact, if you tried to use the unsupported elements with `sudo`, like this:

```
sudo LC_ALL=C grep -i "keyword" <infile >outfile &
```

... then the shell will interpret the redirects and backgrounding (`&`) before running `sudo`, and apply them to `sudo` itself (not to the `grep` command, except indirectly).

Other things `sudo` doesn't support: any sort of complex command, including pipelines, lists (multiple commands separated by `;` or `&`), command groups (with either `( )` or `{ }`), conditional and arithmetic expressions (`[[ ]]` and `(( ))`), logical operators (`!`, `&&`, and `||`), keywords (`if`, `for`, `while`, `case`, etc), or shell aliases and functions.

`time` is an interesting case, because it's a shell keyword *and also* a regular command (generally /usr/bin/time). When you use `sudo time somecommand`, it doesn't recognize `time` as a shell keyword so it uses the regular command executable version instead.

If you want to use the shell (keyword) version, you can run a shell under `sudo` and let it recognize the keyword; something like this:

```
sudo bash -c 'time echo hello'
```

Since that runs a full shell, you can also use any other complex shell syntax you want in this form. But be careful about quoting and such; whatever's after `sudo bash -c` will be run through the shell parsing (and quote and escape interpretation) *twice*, so it's easy to get unexpected results.

Comment: Of course sudo doesn't support compound commands and redirection ! Those are shell features. Sudo itself is a command. Now, if it supported specifying output files via some flag like `strace -o` for example, that'd be different story

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy It's obvious *if* you have a clear understanding of what's done by the shell and what's done by `execl()` et al. (Well, except for variable assignments; it's not obvious that `sudo` would support those.) But a lot of people aren't clear on that, so I thought It'd be best to just go down the list of syntax elements and cover which work & which don't.

Comment: Indeed, understanding the underlying syscalls and mechanics helps.  I've nothing against the answer, in fact I like it hence +1ed. As for `execl()`, consider adding a note about that.  Overall, very helpful answer.