# Is each `time` in these examples a keyword or `/usr/bin/time`?

Tags: time, time-utility

In the following examples, is each `time` a keyword or `/usr/bin/time`? Why, or how do you find it out?

can a keyword be a command?

Or does the keyword `time` apply to an empty command? (I might have asked this somewhere in post or comment, but I can't find it)

Thanks.

```
$ time time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

$ time

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `time time`, both are the built-in from bash, none is the external `/usr/bin/time` command.

This is possible because the `time` built-in takes a pipeline as its arguments, but `time` itself is a pipeline, so multiple calls are possible.

If you look at bash source code, you'll even find comments referring to this [special case](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?h=bash-4.4#n2895), looking for a call to `time` following another `time` or `time -p`.

You only see the output once because `time` is implemented by [setting a bit flag](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/parse.y?h=bash-4.4#n1285), so calling it more than once has no effect since it's just setting the same bit on that pipeline...

This, however, calls it in two separate pipelines, so you see the output twice:

```
$ time { time; }

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s

real    0m0.000s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

You can see results using the external `/usr/bin/time` by calling it explicitly with the path... Or using `\time` (the leading `\` prevents the shell from using a built-in) or using the `command` built-in (as in `time command time`), for example:

```
$ time command time
Usage: time [-apvV] [-f format] [-o file] [--append] [--verbose]
       [--portability] [--format=format] [--output=file] [--version]
       [--quiet] [--help] command [arg...]

real    0m0.002s
user    0m0.000s
sys 0m0.000s
```

As you see, the external `/usr/bin/time` complains when it's called with no arguments... So that's what you're seeing there. (Also, if you use it on an actual command, you'll notice the output format is different from that of the bash built-in.)

Comment: Thanks. Is `time` timing an empty command?

Answer (score 0):

Could be both depending on your setup.
You can see what it is on your system with this command:

```
$ type time
time is a shell keyword
```

In your example both time in `time time` will point to the same command.

Comment: _builtin_ and _keyword_ are two different concepts and have different parsing rules. For example, builtins can be quoted but keywords can't: `"echo" foo` will run the `echo` builtin but `"time" command` will run the `time` external command instead of the `time` keyword. Also note that POSIX requires `time` to be an external command, not a builtin nor a keyword.

Comment: @nxnev [well](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html): "In the KornShell, time is a shell reserved word that can be used to time an entire pipeline, rather than just a simple command. The POSIX definition has been worded to allow this implementation."

Comment: I remember the original question being quite different and my answer making more sense at that point. Either way, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you see only one output in the first example, this is a shell bug.

In shells that re-implement the `ksh` concept where `time` is a `keyword`, `time` without arguments print the timing for the whole pipeline that in this special case is just the single `time` keyword.

If you call `time time`, the first time prints the timing for the whole pipeline and the second `time` prints the timing for itself only.

So the `time` keyword alone indeed is a keyword before an empty command.