# How can we make `time` apply to a pipeline or its component?

Tags: bash, pipe, time

```
time command1 | command2
```

Does `time` apply to `command1` or `command1 | command2`?  If your answer is  one of the two, how would you specify the other?

Could you explain your answer based on the grammar of bash or how the shell interprets the command?

When the shell parses the command, does it recognize `time` as a reserved word before recognizing `|` as a control operator? Does the order between  recognizing `time` as a reserved word and recognizing `|` as a control operator determines whether `time` applies to `command1` or `command1 | command2`?

Thanks.

Comment: From your previous question: the [accepted answer's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444079/70524) second line is: "This is possible because the time built-in takes **a pipeline** as its arguments", and [the third answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444075/70524): "time is a shell keyword".

Comment: @muru That is a different question. My question here is whether `time` applies to the pipeline or just its first component.

Comment: And the part of "the time built-in takes a pipeline as its arguments" you're having trouble understanding is?

Comment: _"Does the order determines whether `time` applies to `command1` or `command1 | command2`?"_ The "order" of what? I'm writting an answer so I'd want to know what you meant by this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> ```
> time command1 | command2
> ```
>
> Does `time` apply to `command1` or `command1 | command2`?

`time` is usually implemented in two ways: as an external command and as an internal feature of a given shell (I say "feature" because it depends on how the shell implements it, though I've only seen it as a reserved word). So, assuming there's at least an external `time` on the system, **the actual answer depends on which shell the user is running and, if applicable, how `time` is implemented in such shell**.

According to the tags you are using Bash as your shell, which has an internal `time`, and I'll assume GNU `time` as the external one for simplicity's sake.

Bash `time`:

- Is a reserved word.
- It applies to entire pipelines.
- It can be used with internal commands/functions/reserved words.

GNU `time`:

- Is an external command.
- It applies to simple commands.
- It cannot be used with internal commands/functions/reserved words unless these were invoked within a shell.

**In your specific scenario, as you are running Bash, `time` applies to `command1 | command2`**. If you were using a shell without an internal `time` but an external `time` is present on the system, it would apply to `command1`.

---

> **Q:** If your answer is one of the two, how would you specify the other?

Applying `time` to `command1` within Bash:

- Using `{ … }` to limit `time`'s scope:

  ```
  { time command1; } | command2
  ```
- Running the external `time` command:

  ```
  # Using the `command` builtin
  command time command1 | command2

  # Using `env`
  env time command1 | command2

  # Escaping/quoting the `time` word
  \time command1 | command2
  'time' command1 | command2

  # Explicitly running the external `time` command
  /usr/bin/time command1 | command2
  ```

Applying `time` to `command1 | command2` with GNU `time`:

- Placing the pipeline in an external file and running it:

  ```
  time ./script.sh
  ```
- Invoking a shell and running the pipeline within it:

  ```
  time sh -c 'command1 | command2'
  ```

---

> **Q:** Could you explain your answer based on the grammar of bash or how the shell interprets the command?

Bash documents its `time` in the [3.2.2 Pipelines](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html) chapter of its manual:

> The format for a pipeline is
>
> ```
> [time [-p]] [!] command1 [ | or |& command2 ] …
> ```
>
> The reserved word `time` causes timing statistics to be printed for the pipeline once it finishes.

GNU `time` documentation is available via `info time` and `man time`:

> The format of the `time` command is:
>
> ```
> time [option...] COMMAND [ARG...]
> ```
>
> `time` runs the program `COMMAND`, with any given arguments `ARG...`. When `COMMAND` finishes, `time` displays information about resources used by `COMMAND`.

POSIX documents [the standard `time`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/time.html), which is the base for many `time` implementations:

> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
> time [-p] utility [argument...]
> ```
>
> **DESCRIPTION**
>
> The `time` utility shall invoke the utility named by the `utility` operand with arguments supplied as the `argument` operands and write a message to standard error that lists timing statistics for the utility.
>
> When `time` is used as part of a pipeline, the times reported are unspecified, except when it is the sole command within a grouping command (see [*Grouping Commands*](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_01)) in that pipeline.
>
> **RATIONALE**
>
> In the KornShell, `time` is a shell reserved word that can be used to time an entire pipeline, rather than just a simple command. The POSIX definition has been worded to allow this implementation.
>
> The term `utility` is used, rather than `command`, to highlight the fact that shell compound commands, pipelines, special built-ins, and so on, cannot be used directly. However, `utility` includes user application programs and shell scripts, not just the standard utilities.

---

> **Q:** When the shell parses the command, does it recognize `time` as a reserved word before recognizing `|` as a control operator?

While Bash's manual does not explicitly mention this information, [POSIX clearly states](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10_01) the order of recognition:

> **2.10.1 Shell Grammar Lexical Conventions**
>
> The input language to the shell must be first recognized at the character level. The resulting tokens shall be classified by their immediate context according to the following rules (applied in order). These rules shall be used to determine what a "token" is that is subject to parsing at the token level. The rules for token recognition in [Token Recognition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_03) shall apply.
>
> 1. If the token is an operator, the token identifier for that operator shall result.
> 2. If the string consists solely of digits and the delimiter character is one of `<` or `>`, the token identifier **IO_NUMBER** shall be returned.
> 3. Otherwise, the token identifier **TOKEN** results.
>
> Further distinction on **TOKEN** is context-dependent. It may be that the same **TOKEN** yields **WORD**, a **NAME**, an **ASSIGNMENT_WORD**, or one of the reserved words below, dependent upon the context.

In short: **operators are recognized before reserved words**.

---

> **Q:** Does the order between recognizing `time` as a reserved word and recognizing `|` as a control operator determines whether `time` applies to `command1` or `command1 | command2`?

Not really, even if `time` is keep as a reserved word it could be programmed to apply to simple commands instead of entire pipelines (though I don't know any shell which has done this). **What matters is how `time` is implemented, not its order of recognition**.

Comment: As I noted in [another comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/444071/is-each-time-in-these-examples-a-keyword-or-usr-bin-time?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment805385_444075), POSIX allows `time` to be a keyword.

Comment: Isn't [`command` also POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html)? Also, in Bash, you could quote the keyword, so it won't recognize it as such: `\time foo` runs the external command `time`

Comment: @muru Yes, but my point is that POSIX does not require `time` to be a keyword. In the same page both you and I linked says: _"When time is used as part of a pipeline, the times reported are **unspecified**, except when it is the sole command within a grouping command in that pipeline"_. And, in the "unspecified" definition: _"The value or behavior may vary among implementations that conform to POSIX.1-2017. An application should not rely on the existence or validity of the value or behavior."_. That's why I wrote: _"In shells **without** a `time` reserved word, `time` applies to `command1`"_.

Comment: @nxnev that maybe your point, but you have repeatedly said that POSIX `time` *has* to be external. My point is that POSIX makes no such requirement.

Comment: @ilkkachu 1) `command` is POSIX, but IMHO using that workaround in a shell where `time` is not a keyword but an external command is redundant; using it in Bash (and KSH, and ZSH, ...) makes more sense. 2) That's right, just added that example. Thanks!

Comment: @muru It may be a bit late but yes, you're right. I rewrote the answer to correct this issue. Feel free to edit the answer or leave another comment if this correction is not enough or some others errors arise.

Comment: Excellent answer.